# How to calculate contributions to the granularity adjustment

Tags: risk-management, banking-regulations, basel, allocation

In the Basel pillar 2 framework a granularity adjustment is introduced. While the capital requirements in pillar 1 do not take concetrations into account, this is meant to be covered with this adjustment in pillar 2.
In [Gordy and Lütkebohmert: Granularity Adjustment for Regulatory Capital Assessment](https://www.ijcb.org/journal/ijcb13q3a2.htm) a simplified adjustment is proposed (formula 17):
$$
GA = \frac{1}{2 K^*} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 C_i \left(\delta (K_i + R_i) + K_i \right),
$$
where $n$ is the number of assets, $s_i = \frac{A_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n A_j}$ is the fraction of exposure $A_i$ over the total exposure;$C_i$ depends on $LGD_i$, $R_i$ is the expected loss $R_i = PD_i \cdot E[LGD_i]$, $\delta$ is a regulatory constant and $K_i$ is the capital requirment for exposure $i$. Finally, $K^*$ is the weighted average capital requirement:
$$
K^* = \sum_{j=1}^n s_i K_i.
$$

Thus, $GA$ takes into account risk via $PD$ and $LGD$ as well as concentration via $s_i$.

How can we attribute this number to the individual assets?

A straight forward expression would be the summand in the above sum:
$$
GA_i = \frac{1}{2 K^*} s_i^2 C_i \left(\delta (K_i + R_i) + K_i \right).
$$

1. However, by definition all these contributions are positive, and one could expect negative contributions in certain scenarios (e.g. if concentration is reduced by adding a position of small risk and small weight).
2. If I did the calculations right, then the above expression for $GA_i$ is not the derivative of $GA$ w.r.t. $s_i$ multiplied by $s_i$ as the Euler allocation would indicate:
   $$
   s_i \cdot \frac{d GA(s)}{d s_i} \neq GA_i.
   $$
   Thus the allocation by $GA_i$ is not an "Euler-allocation".

The questions I would like to discuss:

1. Is there any literature on attribution of the granulrarity adjustment? I have not found any.
2. Although the definition of $GA_i$ above comes very natural due to the functional form of $GA$ it seems to be counter-intuitive. Which alternatives are there?

EDIT: I try to illustrate the derivative in the following.
Set $d_i = C_i \left(\delta (K_i + R_i) + K_i \right)$ so that we can write the above formula more compactly:
$$
GA = \frac{1}{2 K^*} \sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 d_i,
$$
where $K^* = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i K_i$.
Then my manual calculations yield (we need the product rule, as $K^*$ is a function of $s_i$):
$$
\frac{d GA(s)}{d s_i} = \frac{s_i d_i K^* - K_i/2  \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 d_i} { (K^*)^2}.
$$
Using the same notation for the summand above we would compare this (with the factor $s_i$ to pass from the marginal contribution to the allocation) to:
$$
GA_i = \frac{1}{2 K^*} s_i^2 d_i.
$$
Let us write the expression above with the weight $s_i$:
$$
s_i \cdot \frac{d GA(s)}{d s_i} = \frac{s_i^2 d_i K^* - s_i \cdot K_i/2  \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 d_i} { (K^*)^2},
$$
which can be written as:
$$
s_i \cdot \frac{d GA(s)}{d s_i} = \frac{s_i^2 d_i}{K^*} - s_i\frac{K_i/2  \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n s_i^2 d_i} { (K^*)^2}.
$$
Using the above, the Euler-like attribution does not equal the allocation by the summands.

Comment: Hi Ric, did you miss the derivative of $K^*$ w.r.t. $s_i$? If you take that into account, you could come up with a decomposition of the form $f=\sum_i s_i b_i$, no?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I tried the derivative but I did not manage to find a nice algebraic form. I wonder whether anything else than the summands above could result at all. Don't we need some assumptions to be fulfilled for the Euler allocation?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I added the derivative in the EDIT above. Does not look, what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ric, yes. What we need is a homogeneous function (of degree one) for this to work. I tried it a bit and found that it seems that this function is of degree one neither in $s_i$ nor in $A_i$, even if we make the sensible assumption that $K_i = \beta_i + \gamma_i * A_i$....

Comment: @Kermittfrog thank you for trying! I recently got a copy of [Calculating capital charges for sector concentration risk](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328357107_Calculating_capital_charges_for_sector_concentration_risk) where they say " The proposed approach implies a simple and intuitive allocation of the resultant capital charge and is highly suitable to calculate capital charges for sector concentration risk under Pillar 2 of the Basel regulatory framework.". Maybe this leads to something.